# get the margin size of an element with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

How can I get the properties of an element with jquery? I want to get the size of the margin of a div in particular.

I have set the style of the div in a .css file, for instance,

```
.item-form {
  margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
  background: blue;
}
```

the html,

```
<form>
...

<div class="item-form">
   <textarea class="autohide"></textarea>
</div>

...

</form>
```

I tried with this code, but it fails obviously,

```
$(".autohide").each(function(){

var $this = $(this);
alert($this.parents("div:.item-form").css("margin"));


});
```

any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The CSS tag 'margin' is actually a shorthand for the four separate margin values, top/left/bottom/right.  Use `css('marginTop')`, etc. - note they will have 'px' on the end if you have specified them that way.

Use `parseInt()` around the result to turn it in to the number value.

> NB. As noted by Omaty, the order of the shorthand 'margin' tag is: **`top right bottom left`** - the above list was not written in a way intended to be the list order, just a list of that specified in the tag.

Comment: The correct order of the magin properties is : `top right bottom left` Source : [http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that parseInt('45 gobbledeygook'); yielded 45. JavaScript, u crazy!

Comment: @WillMorgan: It copes fine with garbage after the integer portion, but will only allow whitespace before it.

Comment: Beware that in IE7/8 if your margin hasn't been explicity set to something `.css('marginTop')` will return `auto` instead of 0px. So when you run parseFloat or parseInt you'll get **Nan**.

Comment: @EasyCo: Good point.  IE7 has a generally buggy implementation of `margin-top` so always worth being wary if dealing with that browser.

Comment: Why not be precise? `parseFloat()` !

Comment: @MartinR. Because generally speaking, we don't have partial pixels on screens.

Comment: @Orbling I don't think this is a good reason, as it depends on how the value is used in Javascript. Simple example: Maybe you multiply the value by a 100 and use the result as some pixel value. Now in the worst case, the you are off by a 100 pixels.

Answer (score 21):

You'll want to use...

```
alert(parseInt($this.parents("div:.item-form").css("marginTop").replace('px', '')));
alert(parseInt($this.parents("div:.item-form").css("marginRight").replace('px', '')));
alert(parseInt($this.parents("div:.item-form").css("marginBottom").replace('px', '')));
alert(parseInt($this.parents("div:.item-form").css("marginLeft").replace('px', '')));
```

Comment: -1 this will cause string concatenation when trying to add it to an integer.

Comment: And the correct answer is..... alert(parseInt($this.parents("div:.item-form").css("marginTop"),10));

Answer (score 11):

Exemple, for :

```
<div id="myBlock" style="margin: 10px 0px 15px 5px:"></div>
```

In this js code :

```
var myMarginTop = $("#myBlock").css("marginBottom");
```

The var becomes "15px", a string.

If you want an Integer, to avoid NaN (Not a Number), there is multiple ways.

The fastest is to use native js method :

```
var myMarginTop = parseInt( $("#myBlock").css("marginBottom") );
```

Answer (score 6):

From [jQuery's website](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin,
>   background, border) are not supported.
>   For example, if you want to retrieve
>   the rendered margin, use:
>   $(elem).css('marginTop') and
>   $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on.